# How to show that the angle at intersections of concentric ellipses with a radial line is constant?

Tags: geometry, conic-sections

I'm looking for a proof that the angle at intersections of concentric ellipses with a radial line remains constant as you move from one concentric ellipse to another.

For example, a series of concentric ellipses of different sizes are centered on a point of origin.
The radial lines from the point of origin outwards that trace the semi-major and semi-minor axis of the concentric ellipses only form right-angles at each intersection with the concentric ellipses.

How may one show that the other radial lines forming non-perpendicular intersections with the concentric circles form a constant angle with respect to the same radial line?

Comment: I hope my edit above clarifies and adds some context to the geometry proof problem. Thanks

Comment: To be clear: The angles are formed by the radial line and the *tangent* lines to the ellipses at the points of intersection, yes? If so, then "concentric" is clearly not enough of a constraint. A circle is an ellipse, and the tangent at the intersection with any radial line makes a right angle, where this isn't true for a non-circle ellipse. So, the ellipses need the same *eccentricity*. Moreover, you not only want the centers aligned, but you want the major and minor axes to be aligned; otherwise, one ellipse could be rotated with respect to another, throwing-off the property you describe.

Comment: I see, yes.  The angles are between the radial line and the tangent lines to the ellipses at the points of intersection. The concentric ellipses also have the same eccentricity, and have semi-major and semi-minor axes aligned.

Comment: But then ... Ellipses with the same eccentricity are *similar*. Arranging them with a common center, and aligning their axes, we have that a simple dilation transformation carries any one ellipse to any other (and fixes any radial line); since dilations preserve angles, we're done.

Comment: Oh, really, OK.  How to show that to someone that needs convincing....? (not me btw)

Comment: Perhaps carefully drawing the tangents at the points of intersection should do the trick...  These would be parallel, and so would more visually show that the angles between the tangents and the radial line are the same.

Comment: Does this someone understand similarity? As I described, the only way the question makes sense is if the ellipses have the same eccentricity (that is, the same *shape*) and are oriented in the same way. Consequently, the whole ellipse/radial-line/tangent-line configuration from one ellipse to the other is just a matter of *scale*. If the someone understands that doubling the sides of a triangle doesn't affect its angles, then the someone should understand that scaling in general doesn't affect angles.

Comment: Yes, the simple triangle example should help. Thank you!

Comment: The facts that all ellipses have the same eccentricity and that their axes are aligned are vital and should be edited into the question itself, not buried in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

If someone is not convinced by dilation argument, you can also prove the fact in the following way:

The equation of ellipse is:

$$\frac{x^2}{a^2}+\frac{y^2}{b^2}=1$$

So the slope of the tangent is:

$$\frac{x}{a^2}+\frac{yy'}{b^2}=0$$

$$y'=-\frac{b^2x}{a^2y}\tag{1}$$

Now draw two ellipses with semi-axis $(a_1,b_1)$ and $(a_2,b_2)$. For concentric ellipses (with the same center and eccentricity):

$$\frac{b_1}{a_1}=\frac{b_2}{a_2}\tag{2}$$

Draw a line $p$ passing through origin intersecting ellipses in points $(x_1,y_1)$ and $(x_2, y_2)$. Obviously:

$$\frac{x_1}{y_1}=\frac{x_2}{y_2}\tag{3}$$

By combining (1), (2) and (3):

$$y_1'=-\frac{b_1^2x_1}{a_1^2y_1}=-\frac{b_2^2x_2}{a_2^2y_2}=y_2'$$

So both tangents have the same slopes which means that the tangents are parallel and therefore their angles with respect to line $p$ must be equal.

**EDIT**: I have assumed that concentric ellipses must have the same center and the same eccentricity. Eccentricity of an ellipse is defined with:

$$e=\sqrt{1-\frac{b^2}{a^2}}$$

So two ellipses with the same center are concentric only if (2) holds.

Comment: Equation $(2)$ asserts the *similarity* (and axis-alignment) of the ellipses, not the concentricity. Using the standard form of the ellipse equation guarantees that they have the same center.

Comment: @Blue: What is your definition of "concentric ellipses"?

Comment: "con-centric" = "same center".

Comment: True for circles, but that would mean that ellipses $x^2+y^2/100=1$ and $x^2/100+y^2=1$ are concentric too. It does not make any sense (at least to me) and it also invalidates the problem statement completely.

Comment: Whether the problem statement makes sense isn't relevant, as the author wasn't particularly precise in making that statement in the first place. Even so, I'd resist overloading "concentric" with shape information; we have "similar" to describe matching shapes. (Note that the problem also requires that the ellipses in question have the same orientation, which even the overloaded "concentric" misses ... unless we *further* overload the term to cover orientation.) Compare "confocal", used for *arbitrarily-eccentric* conics that share foci; "same shape"-ness is not part of the definition.